# Book request Fuchsian Groups

Tags: book-recommendation, hyperbolic-geometry

I am currently going through the book *Fuchsian Groups* by *Svetlana Katok* for preparing for my seminar talk (getting familiar with the topic). The book is ok, but I like to have some other references since most of the time, different authors have different perspectives. I searched on the internet for some books about Fuchsian Groups, but as far as I can see, there are no other covering just this topic. Also I found a book about modular forms which has a nice introduction to them. So my question is: **Can someone recommend a good book which introduces Fuchsian Groups other than the one by Svetlana Katok?**

Comment: What in particular about Fuchsian groups do you want to talk about ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are many lecture notes and other material on the web about Fuchsian groups. Just to give an example of another book:

$\bullet \;$ Topics on Riemann Surfaces and Fuchsian Groups, by Emilio Bujalance García,A. F. Costa,E. Martínez.

Further references are also given at [Mathoverflow](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/260193/why-are-fuchsian-groups-interesting). If you search a bit yourself, you will find much material.
You already may have seen the [Reading material list for Fuchsian groups](http://www.maths.manchester.ac.uk/~cwalkden/hyperbolic-geometry/limit_sets.pdf).

The more interesting question is: what is really *relevant* for your seminar talk.

Comment: I took the liberty of editing the link to the reading list, so that it goes directly to the document, instead of via Google.

Comment: Thank you very much. I did not know how to do this.